# Caching in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to understand what all SQL's can be utilized for result cache.

Consider multiple scripts pulling data from a big table and later perform different operations.
If we create a volatile table using the BIG Table after apply the common filter used in all the scripts, why this doesnt use Result Cache. Considering the BIG table data doesnt change.

In below example, Script1 Step 1 will use Compute. Will the same step in other script use Compute or use Result Cache

Script1:
STEP 1:CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEST
(SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE CODE='TEST')

STEP 2:UPDATE VT_TEST
SET COL1='TEST1'

Script2:
STEP 1:CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEST
(SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE CODE='TEST')

STEP 2:UPDATE VT_TEST
SET COL1='TEST2'

Scriptn:
STEP 1:CREATE VOLATILE TABLE VT_TEST
(SELECT COL1,COL2 FROM BIG_TABLE WHERE CODE='TEST')

STEP 2:UPDATE VT_TEST
SET COL1='TESTn'

Answer (score 0):

The answer is maybe. In the section of the documentation discussing result set cache reuse, it lists seven criteria that must be met in order to use the result set cache. If it meets all seven, it can use the result set cache but it's not guaranteed.

If you want to ensure that Snowflake uses the result set cache, you can use the result_scan table function:

```
use warehouse test;

-- Grab some rows
select * from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."ORDERS" limit 1000;

-- Set the id variable for later use
set id = last_query_id();

-- Suspend the warehouse to show it won't resume on next statement
alter warehouse test suspend;

-- Use a result from the result set cache
select * from table(result_scan($id));
```

In many and perhaps most cases, you don't need to create a volatile table at all. You can simply execute a query that returns rows, and reuse the results for 24 hours from the result set cache. In other words, rather than doing an insert as select, simply do a select and grab the query ID. You can then use the results from the result set cache for 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Let's suppose I am writing a table load process using SnowSQL with Multiple SQL statements being executed for transforming the data from different tables. Generally we make use of Volatile Tables for storing intermediate data which is used in further Joins/Transformations. Doing a SELECT instead of creating Volatile Table, I assume it will write all the rows to the SnowSql log.

Comment: Even this LAST_QUERY_ID() does it capture id for this session only. Or any session running in parallel considering Snowflake account for a Enterprise Prod Workload

Comment: The LAST_QUERY_ID() applies to the current session. The result_scan() table function will work for 24 hours for the same user. If you need to access the result set cache from a different session, grab the query id and store it somewhere for later use. The result_scan table function operates like a temp table, but living 24 hours instead of the duration of the session. You have to reference it by query ID or using the last_query_id() function. You can also specify -1, -2 in the parameter for last_query_id() to specify the query that happened 2 back, 3 back, etc. but always for that session.

Comment: Thanks Greg. What about my first Concern. If I run select columns in SnowSQL and try to use that result in the separate SnowSQL script wont it write the results to the logs lets suppose I am running the script from Linux

Comment: It will only return the rows to the SnowSQL session that executes the select.